# How to get the position of music in pygame that is playing?

Tags: python

I want to play music and get its position in seconds or minutes of when the music is playing. I used the pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() but the code is not working.

```
def f5secforward():
    print(pygame.mixer.music.get_pos())
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0,pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()//1000+5)
    print(pygame.mixer.music.get_pos())
```

the first 'get_pos' works but after I change the current position of the song with pygame.mixer.music.play(loop,time) it assigns the value of the get_pos to 0

I have searched more and I just found out that get_pos() is not taking where the music is playing it just get the time that the Python mixer is busy.
Is there any solutions?

Comment: i think this is the only way

Answer (score 1):

If you store the first get_pos as an integer (say "oldsongtime") then add the time the second get_pos produces (in your function it will be close to 0) and the time you're adding on (5000) you should get about the right time.

I say about because when I tried to make my own fast forward function the track sometimes jumped much further forward than it should have. Might be something to do with my pre_init not using the default frequency (on all the PCs I've used 44,100 Hz is too slow).

```
def f5secforward():
    oldsongtime = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
    change = 5000
    print(oldsongtime)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0, (oldsongtime+change)/5000)
    addedtime = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()
    print(addedtime)
    currenttime = oldsongtime+change+addedtime

    return currenttime
```